# Один или несколько файлов?

Tags: ajax, php

Ребят, как лучше будет:

- Использовать 1 php файл для ajax (для всех методов)
- Или не сколько. Каждый метод - отдельный php файл

Например:

```
В первом случае я буду делать все ajax запросы на www.example.com/ajax.php?m=showMore или www.example.com/ajax.php?m=addComment,

а во втором случае www.example.com/ajax/showMore.php или www.example.com/ajax/addComment.php
```

Первый для меня удобнее. В AJAX.php я принимаю основные, обязательные get-параметры. Там же их чекаю, а потом уже подгружаю метод (require_once). Не нагрузит этот способ систему?

А во втором мне придется писать один и тот же код в десятках файлов...

---

ИЛИ в этом вообще разницы нет?

Comment: 1-й способ лучше

Comment: > Не нагрузит этот способ систему?

В первом случае придет и выполнится сто запросов, и во втором тоже. Где будет больше нагрузка?

Comment: Чем меньше точек входа в скрипт, тем лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне лично нравится второй способ - url короче. Но на самом деле все можно сделать красиво на apache/nginx, которые будут преобразовывать один тип урлов в другой, более того, даже поддерживать оба типа и фронтенд часть даже не будет знать, какой сейчас бекенд (то есть php или там вообще все на ассемблере переписано)

Оценивать нагрузку, не видя кода - сложно, но если считать, что код эквивалентный, то, скорее всего, разницы никакой не будет, два файла или пять. Тут я придерживаюсь стратегии, что на одну сущность должна быть одна сущность. Если рассчитывать, что управление комментариями (добавление/удаление/редактирование) - одна сущность, то тогда нужно в один файл. Если же это три разные сущности - тогда и три разных файла.
Как узнать, как правильно? Очень просто. Если в случае с одним файлом получается, что его размер тысячи строк, а функции по 200-300 строк - значит нужно делить. Если всего кода 20 строк, то делить нет смысла.

> А во втором мне придется писать один и тот же код в десятках файлов...

Для начала напишите два типичных "действия", посмотрите, сколько кода нужно сдублировать. Создайте новый файл "библиотеку" и аккуратно вынесите туда дубликаты. Начните писать третье действие, пытайтесь активно использовать библиотеку. Если получается неудобно - переписывайте библиотеку. Через какое то время код будет маленьким и красивым.

Comment: @KoVadim фронт-контроллер должен быть всегда один. Просто потому что DRY.

Comment: Главное, чтобы Ваш DRY не стал "[божественным фронт-контроллером](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)".

Comment: @KoVadim там нет объектов. Там указание конфигурации, подключение автозагрузчиков и непосредственный запуск приложения. Там неоткуда взяться проблеме богообъекта, там другие проблемы бывают, тот же Yii (вот у него с богообъектом проблемы) часть конфигурации выносил в константы, в результате чего поведение некоторых компонентов нельзя было изменить после объявления константы.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что фронтенд вообще не должен ничего знать о бекэнде, при любой конфигурации. :)
  
Согласен с @Etki - должен существовать один файл вида "чёрный ящик" на стыке фронт и бек эндов (вот что бывает, когда юзаешь слова из других языков "как звучат"). Только он должен знать, какой вид запроса ему дали, главное - он возвращает определённую структуру данных в любом случае.